# #Error Handling in SSRS when add sum in expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a report and in one of the fields  is

**=(ReportItems!Textbox1.value-ReportItems!Textbox2.value)
/(ReportItems!Textbox1.value+ReportItems!Textbox2.value)**

which is the division of previous 2 fields and if i have any values for these fields then i get the correct value,but if i dont have any values for the previous 2 fields i mean if they are empty then it returns me #ERROR.

So finally i used VB.Net code like below

**Public Shared Function VarPercent(ByVal Actual As Decimal, ByVal Budget As Decimal) As Decimal
If Budget = 0 Then
Return 0
End If
Return (Actual / Budget)
End Function**

Use Expression as below

**=code.varpercent(ReportItems!Textbox1.value-ReportItems!Textbox2.value)
/(ReportItems!Textbox1.value+ReportItems!Textbox2.value)**   its worked nicely.

See My problem is When i try to add SUM  of fields like below

**=code.varpercent(sum(ReportItems!Textbox1.value-ReportItems!Textbox2.value))
/sum((ReportItems!Textbox1.value+ReportItems!Textbox2.value)  )**

Am getting **#Error**,
Is it righr way to add sum function in expression?
If yes,How can i use SUM function in above expression?
Give any alterenate solutions?

Thanks,

Samba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try casting the values to the appropriate type (...Cint(), CDbl()...).

CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox1.value)